# Does Maven3 require me to store my username and password for my authenticating proxy?

Tags: maven, maven-3

The question kind of says it all.

With Maven3 -- is it requisite to store my username and password in plain text via `conf/settings.xml`?

I had originally stored them, and since removed them. Now I can download dependencies .. but i'm unsure as to whether the settings have been cached or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the [encryption](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html) works for the proxy password as well...Just give it a try.

Comment: yes, the encryption does work with the proxy element in settings.xml; we solved our issue by having our own Nexus server.